# Restsharp request to Stripe give SendFailure error

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, restsharp

I try to use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to send request to the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs). I build my request, but it can't be send because of an authentification error. The request return a 0 error code.

Here's my code :

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.stripe.com");
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator (stripe_key, "");

    var request = new RestRequest("v1/tokens", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("card[number]", card.number);
    request.AddParameter("card[exp_month]", card.expMonth);
    request.AddParameter("card[exp_year]", card.expYear);
    request.AddParameter("card[cvc]", card.cvc);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    Log.trace ("Content : " + response.Content);
    Log.trace ("Status code : " + response.StatusCode.ToString ());
    Log.trace ("Error message : " + response.ErrorMessage);
```

And my output :

```
Content : 
Status code : 0
Error message : Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to use [Stripe.net](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net)?

Comment: Nope, I work on Unity which support only .Net 2.0...

Comment: Ah, that's too bad.
According to the error message, the issue seems to be that your system is unable to connect to `https://api.stripe.com` because it fails to verify the SSL certificate sent by Stripe's API server. If you can, try importing this certificate bundle (from the official Stripe Ruby bindings): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/master/lib/data/ca-certificates.crt

Comment: I've just "solved" my problem at the moment ! As you said, the problem was during the SSL certificate validation. I overrided this validation to always return true, and it's work, I can finally get a token from Stripe ! I thinks it's due to the old version of .NET used by Unity (.NET 2.0). But this solution is not really elegant, so I will try this certificate bundle. Thanks !

Comment: I tried to import the certificates bundle, but it has not solved the problem... I keep my *ulgy* solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I work on Unity 5.3, which use .NET 2.0. This version of .NET seems to have difficulties to validate SSL certificates. This problem forbid SSL connection, that's why I had a "0" response status. To override this validation, I did this :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

All certificates will be validated, so be careful... In my case, I communicate with the Stripe API so in my opinion it's ok ! ;)

Comment: You may want to check if this is PCI compliant, my guess would be that it potentially is not.